# C memory allocation for linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, abstract-data-type

I'm trying to make an Linked List that essentially holds a string (rather than a character array). I keep getting segmentation fault (core dumped) and I'm not sure where/how I'm allocating memory wrong

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct mystring
{
    char letter;
    int size;
    int isHead;
    struct mystring*next;
};

struct mystring * create_empty_string(int size)
{   
    struct mystring * string = malloc(sizeof(struct mystring));
    string->size = size;
    string->isHead = 0;
    return string
}

struct mystring * make_string(struct mystring * list,char * string)
{ 
    for(int i = 0 ; i < strlen(string) ; i++)
    {
        list->letter= string[i];
        list = list->next;
    }
    return list;
}
void printList(struct mystring* list) {

   //start from the beginning
   while(list->letter != '\0') {
      printf("(%c) ",list->letter);
      list = list->next;
   }
}
int main()
{
    struct mystring * string = create_empty_string(10);
    string = make_string(string, "hey");
    printList(string);
}
```

Comment: Set a high warning level and pay attention to the warnings. E.g., `..\main.c:19:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function` (your function doesn't return anything when is says it will return something)

Comment: 'string->letter = malloc(sizeof(char));' no.  How many errors/warnings did you get from the compiler?

Comment: 2014.c:18:17: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'void *' [-Wint-conversion]
        string->letter = malloc(sizeof(char));
                       ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2014.c:21:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type] 
} these are the 2 warnings I got

Comment: OK, well, the reason for those warnings needs to get fixed.

Comment: I fixed the return warning, the only warning I have now is with the letter

Comment: You never assign `next` to anything.

Comment: Please don't edit question code so as to invalidate existing answers - it's very confusing and annoying for future visitors, (and current answerers).

Comment: We should not have to repeatedly re-visit your question to fix more and more bugs.  Use your debugger instead of continually editing only what we suggest and reposting 'still doesn't work' ;((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted, your create_empty_string() function is poorly constructed.  I suggest building the linked list one node at a time by feeding individual characters into a function called append_to_string() or similar, which will create a new node and link it to the previously constructed list (or become the list itself if it's the first node).

Answer (score 1):

When `letter` is defined as `char letter;` and your compiler allows you to do `string->letter = malloc(sizeof(char));` without complaining, this means that you are trying to compile without the slightest bit of warnings enabled.  You are not going to go very far like that.  Figure out how to enable ***all*** warnings on your compiler, then perhaps work on the warnings a bit to disable the really annoying ones, and from that moment on your compiler will be helping you to avoid doing such nonsensical things as assigning the result of `malloc()` to a `char`.

Comment: oh great, it appears that you received the warnings, you ignored them, and then you brought it to stackoverflow asking what's wrong.  I will give you another hint: start making use of the "treat all warnings as errors" option of your compiler.  From that moment on your compiler will be helping you to avoid ignoring the warnings.

Comment: okay so I've updated my code and have no warnings, still not sure why I'm getting core dumped

Comment: `while(list->letter != '\0')` keeps looping until `letter` is `'\0'` but you have never set it to `'\0'` so it never stops looping.  On the other hand, you always do `list = list->next;` so you walk out of the end of your list and into the void.  Loop while `list != NULL` instead.

Comment: Also, your `make_string()` function is wrong, it is not allocating any new nodes of the list, it is just doing `list = list->next` into the void.

Comment: You have to allocate the next node before you move into it.

Comment: 'struct mystring * new = malloc(sizeof(struct mystring)); new = list->next;' memory leak.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit This is where my lack of understanding beats me, would checking how many nodes I need before hand correct this ?